# Goland error cannot using right click on project tree and on editor

Tags: go, intellij-idea, editor, goland

i am recently using goland at the first time,
but i cannot using *right click* on **Project Tree** and on **Editor Screen**.

[image]

but in other place i can use the right click . example in terminal screen i can use right click,

[image]

i already reinstall goland, but notthing happen. the issue still exist.
please help me,

Comment: Try `File` -> `Manage IDE Settings` -> `Restore Default Settings`. If that doesn't work it's probably easiest to contact [Jetbrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?goland)

Comment: Using dual monitors? Sometimes I find a right click pops up a window on the other monitor ...

Comment: no i am using single monitor

Comment: @Brits already doing but still not working

Comment: @AhmadAlfanJuniyanto please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270829 comments section.